# Positive connotation of "fluke"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, ambiguity, connotation, idiom-meaning

Many sources ([1](http://www.word-detective.com/2009/04/fluke/), [2](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/fluke?a=american-english), [3](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/249889/idiom-for-describing-an-unintended-benefit/250433#250433), [4](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/128091/an-unlikely-but-very-bad-event-technical-word/128108#128108), [5](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fluke&allowed_in_frame=0), [6](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/fluke#fluke_4), for a start) suggest the word "fluke" has mostly positive connotations when used in the sense of "accident." That is, "a fluke" properly describes a *lucky* accident, not just *any* accident.

However, I sometimes hear this word used to refer to negative and to unmarked accidents. Is such usage, strictly speaking, correct?

To me, the best proof in support would be an example of the broader use by a first-rate writer.

Comment: Basically, "fluke" means "unusual/unexpected situation".  (Yes, what you might call a "lucky accident".)  As such, it does not inherently carry a strongly positive or negative connotation, though I would say other terms are more likely to be used for a negative situation.  But it's a rarely-used term, and finding good examples of its use from known authors is likely to be difficult.

Comment: It's easy to find examples from literature of "fluke" meaning a lucky accident.  Are you interested in these, or are you only interested in literary examples of "fluke" that mean an unlucky accident or a accident that is neither lucky nor unlucky?

Comment: The positive aspect of the word occurs when it is breaded, fried, and served on a plate with tartar sauce. Well, not so positive for the fish.

Comment: The Scots word "flook", attested 1846 as a variation on the English "flux", is a word for diarrhea ... an often unexpected situation. This has not been mentioned before as a a possible origin.

Comment: @ab2 I'm interested only in the special case--using "fluke" for neutral or (preferably) unlucky accidents.

Comment: When I was in engineering school, it was occasionally said of a better brand of electronic instruments that "when it works it's a [Fluke](http://en-us.fluke.com/)".

Comment: I know of no negative connotation to your use of "Fluke". Luck is luck however you can get it. As far as Fluxions we know that Newton suffered from these greatly and even gave them to Leibnitz.

Answer (score 4):

The OP said:

> To me, the best proof in support would be an example of the broader
>   use by a first-rate writer

Here is an example of **fluke** being used, first as an unlucky accident, and second, as a lucky accident.  The quotation is perhaps too long, but it illustrates that the first speaker used fluke as unlucky, and the second as lucky. From E. Phillips Oppenheim, [The Vanished Messenger](http://oppenheim.thefreelibrary.com/The-Vanished-Messenger/17-1#fluke)

> "But how on earth did you get to know about me," Mr. Dunster asked,
>   "and my errand? You couldn't possibly have got me here in an ordinary
>   way. It was an entire **fluke**."
>
> "There, you speak with some show of reason. I have a nephew whom you
>   have met, who is devoted to me."
>
> "Mr. Gerald Fentolin," Mr. Dunster remarked drily.
>
> "Precisely," Mr. Fentolin declared. "Well, I admit frankly the truth
>   of what you say. Your - shall we say capture, was by way of being a
>   gigantic **fluke.** My nephew's instructions simply were to travel down by
>   the train to Harwich with you, to endeavour to make your acquaintance,
>   to follow you on to your destination, and, if any chance to do so
>   occurred, to relieve you of your pocket-book. That, however, I never
>   ventured to expect. What really happened was, as you have yourself
>   suggested, almost in the nature of a miracle. My nephew showed himself
>   to be possessed of gifts which were a revelation to me. He not only
>   succeeded in travelling with you by the special train, but after its
>   wreck he was clever enough to bring you here, instead of delivering
>   you over to the mercies of a village doctor. I really cannot find
>   words to express my appreciation of my nephew's conduct."
>
> "I could," Mr. Dunster muttered, "very easily!"

As for the **neutral** meaning of **fluke**, I cite from [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fluke)

> A chance occurrence: That spring snowstorm was a total fluke

(There are other dictionary definitions of fluke that support a neutral or negative meaning, but this answer is too long already.)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, none of the authors of the following examples are considered to be "first-rate" by anyone (which helps make whatever "evidence" that's contained below fall well short of the "best proof" that you seek), but I’m most familiar with hearing and seeing “fluke” used negatively when the subject is disappointing performances, grades, or test results that might be the result of accidental aberrations or anomalies, such as:

[I was tempted to offer a second interview to see if her **poor performance** was a fluke.](https://books.google.com/books?id=4DdGFYNwnNAC&pg=PA125&dq=%22poor+performance+was+a+fluke%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjR26uuk_bMAhXKez4KHW3UAloQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22poor%20performance%20was%20a%20fluke%22&f=false)

(from *Crazy Good Interviewing: How Acting A Little Crazy Can Get You The Job* by John B. Molidor [with emphasis added], via ‘Google Books’)

or

[[I’d] review the reports very carefully to see if there was a **problem** or if the results were a fluke.](https://books.google.com/books?id=0qxGzqO8rJsC&pg=PA93&dq=%22results+were+a+fluke%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjp3fnCmPbMAhWMMz4KHb43BzQQ6AEIaDAI#v=onepage&q=%22results%20were%20a%20fluke%22&f=false)

(from *Finding the Best and the Brightest: A Guide to Recruiting, Selecting, and Retaining Effective Leaders* by Peg Thoms [with emphasis added], via ‘Google Books’)

or

[[W]hen I got **a D** last week … I thought it was a fluke, but now I have to admit that I’m **floundering** here.](https://books.google.com/books?id=Eh30AgAAQBAJ&pg=PT18&dq=bad+grade+was+just+a+fluke&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi037zRm_bMAhUKHT4KHSZCDjkQ6AEIODAB#v=onepage&q=bad%20grade%20was%20just%20a%20fluke&f=false)

(paraphrased, with emphasis added, from *Trapped: Caught in a Lie* by Melody Carlson, via ‘Google Books’)

Comment: Don't tell anybody, but I don't think  E. Phillips Oppenheim is a first rate writer either.

Comment: Upvote for admitting your authors aren't first rate (although I must admit I thought the fluke/flounder mixed metaphor was inspired)

Answer (score 1):

> "We are quick to dismiss such results as the statistical flukes they
>   almost certainly are"

--Peter W. Huber, *Hard Green: Saving The Environment from the Environmentalists*

He's a good writer; no further